# App hangs when resumed from background

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

So, I've this weird issue which I never came across so far. My app launches properly but when I resume it from background (by moving from to some other app and coming back) it freezes in the task manager itself and the app never resumes.

MyActivity -> Switch to Some App -> Task Manager -> Select MyApp -> Device freezes

I don't have any code being executed in `onResume` or `onPause`, no long running task. Even if I comment out all my code and just keep the layout, then also this is reproduced.

I use ButterKnife for Dependency Injection, Retrofit for Networking - just mentioning in case if its helpful.

Android Studio Version: 2.1.2
Build Tool Version: 23.0.3

**EDIT**
I'm using product flavors. I don't think this should be problem, but mentioning it that can be helpful.

**EDIT 2** The debug version works fine; the issue only occurs when the apk is signed (release version), which seems to be strange!

Comment: are you using real device or emulator?

Comment: Real device. Tested on multiple devices.

Comment: try creating a new project(no code) and run it and see if that will still cause a freeze.

Comment: I just tried with another project (release version). It doesn't seem to show this freezing behaviour. It resumes properly from background.

Comment: onStart() could be the problem. Can you post the code within it ?

Comment: What you have iin your onResume"() ?

Comment: I don't have any code inside `onStart` and `onResume`.